# In the TV show, who cut this person's hand off?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the books, if I recall correctly, it

> was Vargo Hoat that ordered the Dothraki from the Bloody Mummers to cut off Jaime's hand.

However, in the TV show, I think Hoat has not made an appearance, and neither have the Bloody Mummers. Furthermore, the character that cut off

> Jaime's

hand in the TV show is, [apparently, named Locke](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0852965/). However, I don't recall if there was such a character in the books.

Who is he?

Comment: edited the title, pretty soon for such a spoiler :)

Comment: @Jaa-c no problem

Comment: And added spoiler tags to the question, since taking it out of the title doesn't help much if it still shows up in the first line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Locke](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Locke) doesn't appear in the books.

In the TV Series, he is described as:

> Locke is a man-at-arms sworn to House Bolton , considered by Roose Bolton to be his best hunter. He is sent in pursuit of Jaime Lannister after the Kingslayer is freed from Northern captivity by Catelyn Stark .

In the books:

> In the books, "Locke" is the name of a noble house of the North , sworn to the Starks . Its role in the book events is very minor. Their seat is Oldcastle . Only few members of the house are mentioned very briefly throughout the books.

He is basically a replacement for [Vargo Hoat](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Vargo_Hoat)

Comment: But why? Why replace the Goat with Locke? What is the point? I understood most of the changes as simplifications but this just seems perverse.

Comment: It is a simplification to remove Vargo Hoat. What do you mean?

Comment: @TheMathemagician - Keeping Vargo would mean keeping the Bloody Mummers, which is *another* group that a viewer has to track. Remember that this is a 10 episode a season series, not a 600 page book. You don't want to overload the viewers.

Comment: the only regret I have is, like Jamie, I wanted to hear the goat say sapphire

Comment: @TheMathemagician It reduces the number of sub-factions, therefore reducing the overall complexity of the TV show. House Bolton has already been mentioned and plays an important and ongoing role in the series; having one of their retainers play the part of Vargo Hoat makes sense, and it removes the need for yet another faction (which the Brave Companions are, constantly changing sides). Also, they have been effectively removed from the book series! And if you pay attention, the one slightly relevant member of the Mummers has been introduced in the show as well! :)